# Fabric Js can't set value originY bottom

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Tell me, can anyone come across such a problem.
I need to change the reference point of the coordinate system from LT to LB. On the official website there is a test for applying different origins ( http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html ). 
In my project, I was not able to change originY, the same when using fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/borneoBlack/pz4rbken/6/

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  angle: 0,
  fill: '#000',
  originX: 'left',
  //originY: 'bottom' - does not work
  originY: 'top'
});
```

Comment: I tried to use viewportTransform, but I do not need to transform the canvas, but to change the reference point of coordinates, because I get data from the AutoCAD, and there is a point (0,0) in the left bottom corner, not in the left top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`originX` and `originY` reffer to origin of the object related to TL corner of the canvas.
What you can do is to parse all the objects in canvas and adjust the position of the blocks.
Check the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6m034se2/

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  angle: 0,
  fill: '#000',
  originX: 'left',
  //originY: 'bottom' - does not work
  originY: 'top'
});

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(block){
    block.top = canvas.getHeight() - block.top - block.height;
  block.setCoords();
})
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this solution would almost fit, only one thing - as you can see, the hover event is triggered only at the initial position of the element

Comment: I updated my answer. YOu should call `setCoords` after you change the position